# Autofill chrome extension random mail

Tags: windows, javascript

i have this code to generate random mail:

```
var chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890';
var string = '';
for(var ii=0; ii<15; ii++){
    string += chars[Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length)];
}
alert(string + '@domain.com');
```

but on autofill chrome extension how to put this code to fill in the email field??

Answer (score 1):

find simply solution! on mail field insert:

```
{$7}@{$3}.com
```

this insert alphanumeric value on this specific field! or

```
{#7}@{#3}.com
```

to insert random number.
but if i want only lower case a-z how to?